# Is there a way to update the constant value of a large number of constraints in a storyboard?

Tags: xcode, storyboard, xcode-storyboard

Suppose in my storyboard, I have a bunch of controller views that align their content to left and right edges with a certain inset (ex: a padding of 6pts). If I later want to change that padding value, how can I quickly make the change across the entire project? Is there a way to change the constant of all constraints with a certain tag in a Storyboard, or do I have to create a kind of "contentView" class and put it in the base view of every ViewController in my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to get the effect you want using a custom subclass of `NSLayoutConstraint`:

```
class AdjustableConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint {

    @IBInspectable var name: String = ""

    class func setConstant(ofConstraintsNamed name: String, to value: CGFloat) {
        constantForName[name] = value
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(notificationName,
            object: self, userInfo: [nameKey: name])
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
            selector: #selector(AdjustableConstraint.observeAdjustmentNotification(_:)),
            name: AdjustableConstraint.notificationName, object: AdjustableConstraint.self)

        updateConstant()
    }

    deinit {
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self,
            name: AdjustableConstraint.notificationName, object: AdjustableConstraint.self)
    }

    @objc private func observeAdjustmentNotification(note: NSNotification) {
        guard
            let userInfo = note.userInfo
            where userInfo[AdjustableConstraint.nameKey] as? String == name
        else { return }

        updateConstant()
    }

    private func updateConstant() {
        if let newConstant = AdjustableConstraint.constantForName[name] {
            self.constant = newConstant
        }
    }

    private static var constantForName = [String: CGFloat]()
    private static let notificationName = "UpdateAdjustableConstraintConstant"
    private static let nameKey = "name"


}
```

Here's how to use it. For all the constraints in the storyboard that you want to adjust together, set their custom class to `AdjustableConstraint`. (You can select multiple constraints in the document outline to set the custom class of all of them simultaneously.)

Doing this will make Xcode show a new field, “Name”, in the Attributes Inspector for these constraints. Set the name to some string like “customMargin”:

[image: attributes inspector with name field]

In your code, you can set the constant of every `AdjustableConstraint` with a specific name like this:

```
AdjustableConstraint.setConstant(ofConstraintsNamed: "customMargin", to: 10)
```

When an `AdjustableConstraint` is loaded from the storyboard, if you have previously set a constant for its name, it will apply that constant. So this will work for newly-loaded constraints too. You might want to initialize the constant before any any constraint is loaded, by setting it in your app delegate at launch time:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    AdjustableConstraint.setConstant(ofConstraintsNamed: "customMargin", to: 30)
    return true
}
```

Comment: God tier solution.

Comment: Is there a way I can send extra rep?

Answer (score 1):

If the superview to which the subviews are pinned is under auto layout, then in the superview's Size inspector it has a Layout Margins section. So if these subviews are pinned to the layout margins (which is the default anyway when you create a constraint in Interface Builder), all you have to do is change the Layout Margins of the superview.

It's simple to do, but there is no magical way to do it for all the superviews throughout the storyboard in a single move (unless you want to get really bold and edit the storyboard as text — it is just XML, after all).

Comment: That's interesting. It doesn't show up for the root view, so I missed it.

Comment: Correct, because the root view in the storyboard is not under auto layout. (It has nothing to be under auto layout in relation to: it's the root view!) That's why I added that caveat! You can get around this by putting another view inside it, pinned to it on all sides, and using that to contain the subviews.